# Why Haskell alloc huge amounts of memory when working with strings?

Tags: string, memory, haskell

I've written a program in Haskell which had to load and parse big text file in UTF8. The file represents a dictionary with key:value pairs on each line. In my program I want to have a Data.Map container for fast dictionary search. My file is about 40MB, but after loading it to my program 1.5 GB of RAM is used, and never freed. What did I do wrong? Is the memory usage expected?

Here is a code sample from my program:

module Main where

```
import Engine

import Codec.Archive.Zip
import Data.IORef
import System.IO
import System.Directory
import qualified System.IO.UTF8 as UTF8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.UTF8 as BsUtf
import qualified Data.Map as Map

import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Glade

maybeRead :: Read a => BsUtf.ByteString -> Maybe a
maybeRead s = case reads $ BsUtf.toString s of
     [(x, "")] -> Just x
     _         -> Nothing    

parseToEntries :: [BsUtf.ByteString] -> [(BsUtf.ByteString, Int)]
parseToEntries [] = []
parseToEntries (x:xs) = let (key, svalue) = BsUtf.break (==':') x
                            value = maybeRead svalue
                        in case value of 
                            Just x -> [(key, x)] ++ parseToEntries xs 
                            Nothing -> parseToEntries xs 

createDict :: BsUtf.ByteString -> IO (Map.Map BsUtf.ByteString Int)
createDict str = do
    let entries = parseToEntries $ BsUtf.lines str
        dict = Map.fromList entries
    return (dict)

main :: IO ()
main = do

    currFileName <- newIORef ""

    dictZipFile <- B.readFile "data.db"    
    extractFilesFromArchive [] $ toArchive dictZipFile
    dictFile <- UTF8.readFile "dict.txt"
    dict <- createDict $ BsUtf.fromString dictFile

...

searchAccent :: Map.Map BsUtf.ByteString Int -> String -> Int
searchAccent dict word = let sword = BsUtf.fromString $ map toLower word
                             entry = Map.lookup sword dict
                         in case entry of
                            Nothing -> -1
                            Just match -> 0
```

Comment: I'm a little rusty on Haskell, but iirc, the `++` syntax is memory-expensive, where as the cons operator (`:`) is cheap. Is it possible to use something like `(key, x) : parseToEntries xs`? Again . . . my Haskell is very rusty, so this might be way off.

Comment: @jpm, it's memory expensiveness depends on length of the first argument of `++`. In this case it is not relevant.

Comment: @jpm, there are nice pictures about how `++` works in Okasaki book [page 9](http://books.google.ru/books?id=SxPzSTcTalAC&lpg=PP1&hl=ru&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: 40 megs compressed or uncompressed? If it's 40 megs compressed you may need to find a an alternative zip library.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2010-August/081772.html discusses the purpose of the library you are using, which aren't like yours. It took about four minutes to unzip a 23 megabyte zip archive, doing nothing else, but under 10 seconds by other means. I don't think (++) and string vs bytestring are the main trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick answer.
Main problem is that `System.IO.UTF8.readFile` reads file into `String`.

Supposed bottleneck is here:

```
dictFile <- UTF8.readFile "dict.txt"
dict <- createDict $ BsUtf.fromString dictFile
```

When dealing with UTF-8 text it is better to use `Data.Text` instead of `ByteString`.
Try something like this:

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as LT
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding as LT

...
dictFile <- B.readFile "dict.txt"
dict <- createDict $ LT.decodeUtf8 dictFile
```

Another bottleneck is parsing numbers: you are converting `ByteString` to `String` and then `read` it.
It's better to use `Data.Text.Lazy.Read`:

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Read as LT

maybeRead :: LT.Text -> Maybe Int
maybeRead s = case LT.decimal s of
    Left _  -> Nothing
    Right i -> Just i
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Data.Text really takes much less of the RAM memory. But I've used strict version which i think is more economical.

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell `String` type is an indirect (because of laziness) linked list of characters; it is *extremely* wasteful space-wise.  You may wish to try `Data.Text` (from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) instead, for large amounts of text.

(*edit* now that source is up I see the strings are lazy `ByteString` instead of `String`, so this is not relevant.  Profiling is the next step.)

Comment: The program only uses `String` in `maybeRead`, the arguments to which are presumably relatively small.

Comment: Okay, I see you have partial source now and the primary format is UTF8 lazy `ByteString` (which is not ideal but far better than `String`).  It is possible you're too lazy and have thunks built up; the next step is to use profiling to see where the space is going.

Comment: I'm not the asker, but the question has never been edited, so if the source was added in, it must have been in the first five minutes. (Actually, I'm not sure the grace period applies to questions...) However, my previous comment was wrong, as max's answer shows.